# Incrementing a variable through embedded assembly language

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I am trying to understand how to embed assembly language in C (using gcc on x86_64 architecture). I wrote this program to increment the value of a single variable. But I am getting garbage value as output. And ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    x = 4;

    asm("incl %0": "=r"(x): "r0"(x));

    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

**Update** The program is giving expected result on gcc 4.8.3 but not on gcc 4.6.3. I am pasting the assembly output of the non-working code:

```
    .file   "abc.c"
.section    .rodata
.LC0:
.string "%d"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
 main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
pushq   %rbx
subq    $24, %rsp
movl    $4, -20(%rbp)
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax

incl %edx

movl    %edx, %ebx
.cfi_offset 3, -24
movl    %ebx, -20(%rbp)
movl    $.LC0, %eax
movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
movl    %edx, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
movl    $0, %eax
addq    $24, %rsp
popq    %rbx
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: it's okay on my x86_64 linux

Comment: @rakib Did you use gcc? Just in case it is relevant, I am using gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Check the assembly code that gcc is generating. `gcc -S test.c` will make `test.s` with the assembly listing.

Comment: @Arani yes, i've used gcc-4.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to say `x` twice; once is sufficient:

```
asm("incl %0": "+r"(x));
```

The `+r` says that the value will be input *and* output.

Your way, with separate inputs and output registers, requires that you take the input from `%1`, add one, and write the output to `%0`, but you can't do that with `incl`.

The reason it works on some compilers is because GCC is free to allocate both `%0` and `%1` to the same register, and appears to have done so in those cases, but it does not have to. Incidentally, if you want to *prevent* GCC allocating an input and output to the same register (say, if you want to initialize the output before using the input to calculate a final output), you need to use the `&` modifier.

The documentation for the modifiers is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers).